# TS Concepts typename constraint

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, typename, c++-concepts

I'm trying to make a simple example of templated inheritence using a concept as a constraint on subclasses (compiled by gcc with gnu2a and fconcepts). I expected the example below to compile fine, but I can't get it to work:

```
template<class structure>
concept bool Has_Type() {return requires{
    typename structure::type;
};}

template<class sub> requires Has_Type<sub>()
struct structure {
     //using type = typename sub::type;
};

struct child: structure<child> {
    using type = child;
};
```

The concept throws an error, saying that `typename structure::type would be ill-formed`. I can't see why, since child has a type accessible by the `::` operator. I tried this example to see if the idea itself was valid, and this compiled and ran fine:

```
struct child {
    using type = child;
};

template<class it>
auto func() {
    typename it::type f = child();
    return 0;
}

// in a test.cpp file

auto g = func<child>();
```

this makes me think that the idea is supported, so I'm not sure why the concept is failing. Anyone know why?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's because `child` is incomplete at that point. [class.mem]p6 says:

> A class is considered a completely-defined object type (6.7) (or complete type) at the closing } of the
>   class-specifier.

Followed by a few exceptions (like not in member functions). But in the *base-clause*, it is incomplete and so the member `type` is not available to `Has_Type`.